# AES Encryption with CryptoJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, aes, cryptojs

I want to implement AES encryption using JavaScript. Used AES CBC Mode. I have managed to do it in PHP. It looks like:

```
 public function encrypt($value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
          return $value;
        }
        $value = Unicode::convertToUtf8($value, 'UTF-8');
        if ($key = $this->getEncryptionKey()) {
          // Generates from key 1st 16 bytes.
          $iv = mb_substr($key, 0, 16);
          //encrypt message with key
          $message = openssl_encrypt($value, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
          return base64_encode($message);
        }
    }

    public function getEncryptionKey() {
        $key = 'secret';
        $key = Unicode::convertToUtf8($key, 'UTF-8');

        // Make sure the key is the correct size.
        if (strlen($key) < 32) {
          $key = str_pad($key, 32, "\0");
        }

        if (strlen($key) > 32) {
          $key = mb_substr($key, 0, 32);
        }

        return $key;
    }
```

If I give $value = retest2; it gives me **ukUCH0SvgdmM8vTqQumAVg==** output

I know it's right, I tried it using C# as well got the same result. But when I try to replicate this using JavaScript, I wasn't able to produce same PHP's output. Below is the javascript code that I have tried:

```
const message = utf8.encode('retest2');
const password = utf8.encode('secret').padEnd(32, '\0');
const key =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(password);
const iv =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(password.substring(0, 16));

const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {
    iv: iv
});
console.log(btoa(encrypted.toString()));
```

Using the same value I get **dzd4bjNwenduQT09**. 
I have also read other similar questions asked on the same topic here, but I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You're using encryption wrong, textbook wrong. If you encrypt **same** payload, your ciphertext must always be different. That's what initialization vector is for. It has to CHANGE every time you encrypt. But, you even use a part of your key for IV..

Comment: Hi @N.B. thank you for replying, I understood your point. Just one question though how does it works for PHP as shown in above code ? I just want to generate the same string for **retest2** !

Comment: Hi @N.B. I read more about it, Now I understood your point very clearly. Can you please suggest me, how can I achieve the same encryption as PHP. Here I am using Angular and I need to send encrypted key from the Angular app. And sorry for replying late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @symcbean said,

> You shouldn't be using the key or data derived from it as your
>   initialization vector.

I assume, you have no option and you have to use key or data derived from it as your initialization vector.

A few months ago, I had the exact same situation and I did something like this,

```
const message = 'retest2';
let password = 'secret';
if (password.length < 32) {
    password = password.padEnd(32, '\0');
}
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password.substring(0, 16));
password = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password);
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt((message), (password), {
    iv: iv
});
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext));
```

Comment: How do we decrypt the same above code? any idea? I have tried I could not get it done.

Answer (score 0):

These should be comments but space is limited....

You shouldn't be using the key or data derived from it as your initialization vector.

> I know it's right, I tried it using C# as well

You should have shown us the code.

Your openssl call invokes the [key derivation function](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) to create a (better?) encryption key from the data you pass in the third parameter. OTOH, in crypto.js there is [no implicit key derivation](https://github.com/jakubzapletal/crypto-js/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Thanks, @symcbean for replying. I understood your point. I don't have access to the c# code, so I can't share C# code. however, I wrote this PHP code by myself. Can you please suggest what I suppose to do? Like how do I generate the encryption same as PHP.  
BTW I am using Angular 5 framework. I don't have any other workaround, I have to send encrypted value from Angular App.

Comment: Use TLS - that's what its for.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?